# Adding an object to another object C++

Tags: c++, aggregation

I'm trying to simply add an object to another object within a class, for example add player to factory.

For my factory.h

```
class Factory
{
public:

    Factory(void);
    ~Factory(void);
    void addMaze(Maze maze);
    void addPlayer(Player player);
    std::string getSessionTime();
    std::string setSessionTime(std::string time);

    private:

    int m_ID;
    Player m_player;
    Maze m_maze ;
    std::string m_SessionTime;
    std::string m_filePath [50];


    };
```

and then in my Factory class I have:

```
void Factory::addPlayer(Player player)
{
    m_player.add(player); //This is what I feel like I want to do
}
```

So, I'm trying to add a Player to my list of Players, but this won't do it? Am I missing something really obvious? If anyone could help or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: consider using `std::vector<Player>` as a member variable of the class `Factory`.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve, is your factory supposed to have a list of players?

Comment: Fyi you're passing by value, so (assuming no move semantics) the `player` instance in the `Factory` won't be the same as the one which `addPlayer` was called with. It's a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Player m_player;` declares a data member of type `Player`, not a list of players. If you want a list, have a member `std::list<Player>` or the more common `std::vector<Player>`.

Your function could look like

```
void Factory::addPlayer(const Player& player)
{
    m_players.push_back(player);
}
```